# List access giving - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, range

This is my first selenium webdriver program with Python. I need to get values from Excel. Here I am giving two data from excel one User name and Password.

I am getting the first value, but the loop function is not working.

The following code is giving me the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The script is:

```
  def test_Login(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url +"/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('C://Deepak//Test.xlsx')

    sh1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
    rowcount = sh1.nrows
    list_rows = [None]*rowcount

    for n in range(rowcount):
       list_rows[n] = sh1.cell(n, 0).value

    driver.find_element_by_name('userName').send_keys(list_rows[0])
    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(list_rows[1])
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Please take a look at [help], especially the link that covers how to debug simple programs. Debugging your own programs is a key skill to learn. This is a good one to start on.

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in range(rowcount):
   list_rows.append(sh1.cell(n,0).value)
```

I think your problem is `list_rows[n] = sh1.cell(n,0).value` Use list.append(obj) to initialise list elements.

EDIT: Fixed the answer. Previous answer was wrong.

Comment: After Given  list = list(map(str, rowcount) , it showing some syntax error on For loop , How can i overcome this .

Comment: @Deepak I have changed my answer. It should work now.